# Flexbox working in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

[This flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/w5e7c93n/12/) seems to only work in Chrome. I have played with it extensively and tried applying various fixes found at https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Note: JavaScript is employed to resize it based on the background-image height.

I'm curious if anyone can make it work the same in another browser. Thanks for reading.

**Obligatory code:**

CSS:

```
.section-1 {
    background: url("http://img01.deviantart.net/cb2e/i/2011/323/0/3/background_05_1600x1200_by_frostbo-d42mpk5.png") no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.flex-container {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;

    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var img = new Image();
var section = document.getElementsByClassName("section-1")[0];
var flex = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-container")[0];
img.src = window.getComputedStyle(section, null).getPropertyValue("background-image").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

function resize() {
    var bgHeight = section.offsetWidth * img.height / img.width;
    console.log(bgHeight);
    section.style.height = bgHeight + 'px';
    flex.style.height = bgHeight + 'px';
}
window.onresize = resize;
resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using percentage heights on the `<section>` and `.flex-container` `div`, you need to also specify a height for all parent elements, up to and including the `body` and root element (`html`).

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/w5e7c93n/20/

For more details see: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: RE: "You don't really need vendor prefixes anymore". I strongly differ. You can't make that assessment without knowing what the target browser is for that particular project. Android devices < 4.4, or older but still very recent iOS browsers, such as Safari 8 don't support unprefixed flexbox at all. In that, I don't think it is useful or wise to say that prefixed should be dropped at this time.

Comment: @hexalys, that's a very good point. Thanks for the feedback. I was going to revise the wording but ultimately decided to scrap the entire paragraph. The code block in the question makes your point clear.

Comment: The correct answer is actually a JavaScript one that I will be posting later. It has to do with how IE and Firefox both report extra data on dimension calls. I appreciate your help nonetheless.